# Scrapy Outputting Empty CSV file from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, scrapy, web-crawler

I built a spider in Jupyter notebook to crawl the website [www.worldometers.info](http://www.worldometers.info) and it appeared to work in the notebook itself. But when i check the .csv file it is completely empty. Below is the code and ouput:

```
import scrapy

class WorldometersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'worldometers'
    allowed_domains = ['www.worldometers.info']
    start_urls = ['https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/']
    
    def parse(self, response):
        # title = response.xpath('//h1/text()').get()
        countries = response.xpath('//td/a')
        
        for country in countries:
            country_name = country.xpath(".//text()").get()
            link = country.xpath(".//@href").get()
            
            # absolute url
            # absolute_url = f'https://www.worldometers.info/{link}'
            # absolute_url = response.urljoin(link)
            
            # relative url
            yield response.follow(url=link)

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
process = CrawlerProcess(settings = {'FEEDS': {'output3.csv':{'format':'csv'}}})
process.crawl(WorldometersSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Did you use ChatGPT (or other AI) to generate this code?

Comment: why would there be any output?  You enver yield any items from the spider

Comment: No I did not use AI or a Generator, and why does it matter Barry? How does that pertain to this discussion?

Comment: I am following a tutorial and the person teaching me did get output Alexander and I can see the output in my console, I did not add it here on Stack Overflow because of limit restrictions. The question is why does it not show in the csv file when it does show in the console?